# How to add a C-only option in Android.mk?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

In Android.mk, if I do this:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -foo
```

Then -foo is used when compiling both C and C++ code.  I don't do anything to set LOCAL_CPPFLAGS, it presumably inherits all the CFLAGS.  (Why?)

How to set a *C-only* option?

This is needed because some compiler options don't have a matching option with the opposite effect (so you can't unset them), and also I might want completely different defines for C and C++.

(android ndk r9b)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest answer is to build separate static libraries from files with different defines and options.

You can also use the tag mechanism:

```
LOCAL_C_SRC_FILES := $(filter %.c, $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
LOCAL_C-ONLY_CFLAGS := -DDEBUG=1
TARGET-process-src-files-tags += $(call add-src-files-target-cflags, $(LOCAL_C_SRC_FILES), $(LOCAL_C-ONLY_CFLAGS))
```

Answer (score 2):

(This was added to ndk-build system after question and answer)

`LOCAL_CONLYFLAGS := -foo`